# Shifting the position of start image in group of subfigures

Tags: graphics

I am trying to set a group of 5 images together. however for comparison I want 4 of these images to be on top of each other and one needs to be single.

I was able to write code to group 6 subfigures.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure*}[hp!]
\centering
     \begin{center}


%
        \subfigure[image1]{%
            % \label{fig:first}
            \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{imp₁.png}
        }%
%
        \subfigure[image2]{%
            % \label{fig:second}
            \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{imp₂.png}
        }%
%
        \subfigure[image3]{%
            % \label{fig:third}
            \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{imp₃.png}

        }\\%
%
        \subfigure[image4]{%
            % \label{fig:fourth}
            \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{imp₄.png}
        }%
%
        \subfigure[image5]{%
            % \label{fig:fifth}
            \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{imp₅.png}
        }%
%
        \subfigure[image6]{%
            % \label{fig:sixth}
            \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{imp₆.png}
  
        }\\%  
    \end{center}
     \caption{Fasi del processo di impregnazione}
      \label{fig:images}
\end{figure*}        

\end{document}
```

[image]

I would now like to modify it in such a way that the place where there should be the first image is left blank, and it starts with the place of the second image. as shown below, kindly guide me on how to accomplish that.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an invisible rule (height=0pt) to fill the space and the package `subfig`.

[image: c]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{subfig}% added <<<<<

\begin{document}    
    
    \begin{figure*}[hp!]
        \centering
        \rule{0.25\textwidth}{0pt}\hspace*{20pt}
            \subfloat[image1]{%
                % \label{fig:1a}
                \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}
            }\hspace*{20pt}         
            \subfloat[image2]{%
%                \label{fig:1b}
                \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}               
            }\\%            
            \subfloat[image3]{%
%                \label{fig:1c}
                \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}
            }\hspace*{20pt}         
            \subfloat[image4]{%
%                \label{fig:1d}
                \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}
            }\hspace*{20pt}         
            \subfloat[image5]{%
%                \label{fig:1e}
                \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}               
            }\\%  
        \caption{Fasi del processo di impregnazione}
        \label{fig:images}
    \end{figure*}        
    
\end{document}
```

The same result is obtained using the package `subcaption`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}    
    
    \begin{figure*}[hp!]
        \centering
    \rule{0.25\textwidth}{0pt}\hspace*{20pt}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
        \centering
        % \label{fig:1a}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{image1}
    \end{subfigure}\hspace*{20pt}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
        \centering
        %                \label{fig:1b}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}               
        \caption{image2}
    \end{subfigure}\\ \bigskip      
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
        \centering
        %                \label{fig:1c}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{image3}
    \end{subfigure}\hspace*{20pt}   
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
        \centering
        %                \label{fig:1d}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{image4}
    \end{subfigure}\hspace*{20pt}   
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
    \centering
        %                \label{fig:1e}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}               
        \caption{image5}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \caption{Fasi del processo di impregnazione}
    \label{fig:images}
    \end{figure*}        

\end{document}
```